# How to detect enabled QuickEdit on a List or Library from client?

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, csom, sharepoint-rest-api, 2016

When trying to enforce certain business rules on list Forms, there's always the risk that users will use QuickEdit to circumvent them.

Is there a way to detect if QuickEdit is enabled (or whether this option changed)?

[image]

Quick tests show that `SchemaXml` is not affected by changing this radio button (only list version changes) and there's no obvious property to check in REST API or CSOM.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the Quick Edit property value of list using SharePoint REST API.

For all lists on the site:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/_api/web/lists?$select=Title,DisableGridEditing
```

For single list:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listName')?$select=DisableGridEditing
```

If Quick Edit is set to "No", `DisableGridEditing` returns `true` value.

Comment: Thank you Ganesh, but we're using an on-prem 2016, not SPO/O365

Comment: Oh ok. Right now I don't have 2016 environment to test above API. Can you check using it on your 2016 environment? Meanwhile I will check if there is another way to check this in 2016.

Comment: Check [this article](https://blog.aterentiev.com/check-if-list-is-switched-to-quick-edit) which might help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that article is very interesting for UI customization, which is a valid, but rather different scenario. Anyway, very much appreciate your effort, @Ganesh.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict the users from modifying list settings (*ie, changing the Quick Edit settings*) , why can't you restrict them using permission levels?

If you provide '**Contribute**' permission to them, I believe users won't be able to change the settings then.

[image]

I know this is not the answer to your question (*"Is there a way to detect if QuickEdit is enabled (or whether this option changed)?"*), but after understanding the requirement I thought about this approach.

Comment: Thank you for the contribution. Even if they are restricted at some point in time, somebody could have a valid case to re-enable it for a short period of time and then forget to re-disable. We'd like to detect that issue proactively.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, we surely can and will parse the list's Advanced settings page, but a more elegant solution is very welcome.